# Is there a proper way to run tasks using a custom task scheduler?

Tags: c#, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, priority-queue, .net-4.6.1

So I am still really fresh with using task schedulers and threading in general, but am having trouble with a custom task scheduler. Unfortunately, I don't have all my code but will try to be as detailed as possible.

So my task scheduler is based on this [limited concurrency task scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-5.0). Now, I want my tasks to have priority so I also have a separate class that creates and stores some concurrent queues, I am using this [simple priority queue example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-add-bounding-and-blocking).

So how I have it set up is that within the constructor for my tasks scheduler I pass another parameter for the amount queues I want:

```
public LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(int maxDegreeOfParallelism, int numberOfQueues)
```

The constructor then creates a new instance of the priority queue class with the number of queues I want. The only methods I really use from the priority queue class are `TryAdd` and `TryTake`.

Now, the changes I made to the task scheduler were mainly so that I could use the queues from my priority queue class instead of using the list in the example. The first change I had to make was to create an entirely new method for enqueuing tasks. I did this since there is no overload for `QueueTask` that takes more than one parameter and I wanted to create a key-value pair that held a priority level and the task.

```
protected sealed override void EnqueueTask(int Priority, Task task)
{
   // Add the task to the list of tasks to be processed.  If there aren't enough
   // delegates currently queued or running to process tasks, schedule another.

   var item = KeyValuePair<int, Task> (Priority, task);
   lock (PriorityQueueClass._queues) //_queues are the concurrent queues that were created when I 
                                     //initialized my priority queue class. 
   {
       PriorityQueueClass.TryAdd(item);
       if (_delegatesQueuedOrRunning < _maxDegreeOfParallelism)
       {
           ++_delegatesQueuedOrRunning;
           NotifyThreadPoolOfPendingWork();
       }
   }
}
```

The only other method I modify is `NotifyThreadPoolOfPendingWork()`. The only real change in this method is that I use `TryTake` from my priority queue class (which will loop through queues in priority order) to grab an item and pass it into the TryExecuteTask method:

```
 base.TryExecuteTask(item.Value); // item is a key-value pair, so the Value would be the task
```

Here's where I am having trouble. In a separate project, I have a main program (I properly set my references for my task scehduler) where I create some tasks,  create my scheduler, and attempt to schedule my tasks.

```
public static void Main()
{
    // creates a new scheduler with 2 degrees of parralelism and 2 queues
    LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler lcts = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(2,2); 
    
    //Create a few simple tasks
    Task t1 = new Task(Action);  //the actions are just a method that prints some text to output window.
    Task t2 = new Task(Action);  //I make the action in the main method, assume they are in here.
    ...
    
    lcts.EnqueueTask(0,t1); //0 is the highest priority queue
    lcts.EnqueueTask(1,t2); //1 is a lower priority queue
}
```

What happens if I run is that it looks like it is going through all the code, however when it reaches the `base.TryExecuteTask(item.Value)` in the `EnqueueTask` method it throws an exception "execute task may not be called for a task which was previously queued to a different taskscheduler".

Now, I'm not sure if this is even a correct way to start the scheduler as I have usually seen people use the task factory directly or use `task.Start()`. I am calling my `EnqueueTask` method directly because I'm not seeing a better way to assign priority at the moment. But if there is a fault in my thinking, or if there is a better way to merge the task scheduler and priority queue class, then I am all ears.

I need to stick with .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: You might be interested in some of the classes in the old Parallel Extensions Extras package. It had a bunch of custom task schedulers and other data structures. The project died, but it did eventually get ported by someone to netstandard2.1 https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/csharp/parallel/ParallelExtensionsExtras

Comment: Also... Net6 will finally include a priority queue class! API was approved and they have a [story](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43957) for it!